# ASP.NET Validator doesn't fire

Tags: asp.net, validation

I've a problem with a RequiredFieldValidator on a page with two Panels, which represent two different views, i.e. only one panel is visible at one time, but they share same submit button.

By default the "BatchReturnPanel" is visible and "SingleReturnPanel" is hidden, and in this case all validators on page work just fine. But if I hide the "batch.." panel and show "single.." panel (ChangeViewButton click event) then the requieredFieldValidator "DropDownListFieldValidator" doesn't fire up, and page is always considered validated. Why does this happen and how can this problem be solved? Thanks for help/

Below is extract from the ASPX page:

```
<div>
<asp:DropDownList ID="MDDropDownList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="DropDownListFieldValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MDDropDownList" 
InitialValue="-"  ErrorMessage="Please select Master Distributor" EnableClientScript="true" CssClass="error" 
Display="Static" ValidationGroup="Voucher" />

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="BatchReturnPanel">
<p>
<asp:TextBox ID="FirstVoucherTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="Scanner RRS"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="FirstVoucherFieldValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FirstVoucherTextBox" ValidationGroup="Voucher"
        ErrorMessage="Valid Voucher ID for the first voucher in batch is required<br>" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="error" EnableClientScript="false"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</p>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="SingleReturnPanel" Visible="false">
<p>
<asp:TextBox ID="SingleVoucherTextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="SingleVoucherTextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="SingleVoucherTextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
</p>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="VoucherSubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Enter" 
        OnClick="VoucherSubmitButton_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ValidationGroup="Voucher"/>
</div>

<asp:Panel CssClass="grid_4 box" runat="server" ID="ChangeViewPanel">
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="ChangeViewButton" 
        onclick="ChangeViewButton_Click">Single item return mode</asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: why do you have this?`UseSubmitBehavior="false"`

Comment: try to set `FirstVoucherFieldValidator`'s `ValidationGroup` something different than `Voucher` when you click `ChangeViewButton` if `BatchReturnPanel` is visible, else set it `Voucher`.

Comment: In which method are you populating `MDDropDownList`?  Would you be able to show this too?

Comment: Hi Chris, 
I solved the problem by calling Page.Validate("Voucher") but don't understand yet why it happened. The DropDownList is populated by this method which is called on Page_Load if page is not Postback 
 
    private void BindData()
    { this.MDDropDownList.DataSource =             this.RobinEntity.RobinCompanies;
    this.MDDropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
    this.MDDropDownList.DataValueField = "Id";
    this.MDDropDownList.DataBind();

    this.MDDropDownList.Items.Insert(0, "-");
    this.MDDropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use validation group and client side page validation.

```
function Validation() {
        Page_ClientValidate('validationGroupName');

        if (!Page_IsValid) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps